# ClassNotFoundException in deferred task when deployed

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have built an app engine app using Gradle; Gradle manages all the dependencies.

The app accepts some parameters as part of a POST then creates a deferred task to write to a Google Sheet.

When I use `appengineRun` the app runs fine.

When I use `appengineDeploy` and try running the deployed application, the deferred task fails with this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: _ah_queue_deferred: Deferred task failed exception: com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DeferredTaskServlet$DeferredTaskException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiMap$1
```

None of my code uses `org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiMap`, and `gradle dependencies` does not have a single mention of any Jetty dependencies.

Is it possible to get a full stack trace to see what is loading this class?

What could be loading this class, and how can I fix this in a maintainable way (i.e. using Gradle to properly manage dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but a workaround is to add jetty-util to `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.8.v20171121'
```